# Como garantir que a promise é resolvida?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Boas, estou a tentar fazer um pedido `POST` que em caso de insucesso retorna `false` e em caso de sucesso retorna `true`.

O meu problema ocorre porque mesmo com o `await` não espera que a *promise* seja resolvida para devolver o valor para a variável.

```
async login() {
    this.userExist = await this.$root.login(this.email, this.password);
    console.log("User -> " + this.userExist);
}
```

A variável assume sempre o valor de `undefined`.

A função `this.$root.login()` está no ficheiro `vue.js`, sendo que a função `login` está num componente.

```
login(email, password) {
    axios.post('/api/login',{email: email, password: password})
        .then(response => {
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access_token);
            this.$store.commit('define', response.data.access_token);
            this.$router.push('/');
            return true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função `this.$root.login` precisa retornar a Promise do `axios`, dessa maneira `await` pode pegar os retornos de *fulfill* e *reject* da sua promise corretamente.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
/* Se `success` for true requisição OK (200)
   Senão retorna erro 400 */
async function getUser(success) {
    let http_code = success ? 200 : 400;
    
    return axios.get(`https://httpbin.org/status/${http_code}`)
        .then(response => true)
        .catch(error => false)
}


async function login() {
    let userExists = await getUser(true);
    console.log("userExists == ", userExists);
    
    userExists = await getUser(false);
    console.log("userExists == ", userExists);
}

login();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```